# Run pip in python docker

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, pip

I am completely new to docker (on windows 10 machine). I intend to setup a python development environment as a docker container. And most of the reading that I did involved the use of Dockerfile. I want to do it from scratch instead purely using commands.

What I intend to do is very basic requirement: To have python docker image present with me and that I should be able to install more libraries in that image and commit these updates to that image. But I want to do it completely using commands (not via a Dockerfile).

I am using Docker Desktop on windows 10 machine. I did `docker pull python:latest` and it pulled the image like so:

```
C:\Users\MyHomeDirectory>docker pull python:latest
latest: Pulling from library/python
d960726af2be: Pull complete
e8d62473a22d: Pull complete
8962bc0fad55: Pull complete
65d943ee54c1: Pull complete
532f6f723709: Pull complete
1334e0fe2851: Pull complete
062ada600c9e: Pull complete
aec2e3a89371: Pull complete
1ec7c3bcb4b2: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:65367d1d3eb47f62127f007ea1f74d1ce11be988044042ab45d74adc6cfceb21
Status: Downloaded newer image for python:latest
docker.io/library/python:latest
```

Then I did `docker images` and it showed that python latest image is present with a size of `886 MB`.

```
C:\Users\Tejas.Khajanchee>docker images
REPOSITORY    TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED        SIZE
python        latest    5b3b4504ff1f   47 hours ago   886MB
```

I am also able to enter the interactive python by doing `docker run -it python` and it generates the interactive shell:

```
Python 3.9.5 (default, May 12 2021, 15:26:36)
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
>>> import gc
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
>>>
>>> import pandas
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
>>>
>>> import openpyxl
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openpyxl'
>>>
```

But as evident, some of the libraries are not installed. But this is where I get stuck. How do I install libraries into the python image and have the image updated. Also, if this shell is the only thing that I am allowed to do till now, what does the `886 MB` content represent? Also I want to be able to run scripts using this docker image. When I attempt to do this on a very basic hello world script, the following error comes up:

```
C:\Users\MyHomeDirectory\Downloads>docker run -it python a.py
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:367: starting container process caused: exec: "a.py": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.
```

I want to be able to do this purely with commands and not a Dockerfile. Please help.

Comment: can you shell into your container and run `python -m pip install numpy`?  If it were me, I would use a docker file to handle this though.

Comment: No its not allowing me to shell into the container. I did `docker exec -it python /bin/bash`. It gives an error: `Error: No such container: python`.

Answer (score 1):

**First**, looks you confuse the concept of `image` & `container`.

- Docker image: read only, used as basis of container
- Docker container: overlay a writeable layer upon the read only layer of docker image, all container will use image as basis

**Second**, for you, you mentioned you want to install `numpy` in the image, the best way for this is to customized a `Dockerfile` like next:

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM python
RUN pip install numpy
```

Then, build a new image with `docker build -t newpython .`

***BUT***, you mentioned you don't want to use `Dockerfile`, then the replacement is next:

1. Install numpy in a container:

   ```
   docker run -it python /bin/bash
   # pip install numpy
   ```
2. Use `docker ps -a` to get the container id, e.g: `0a6b4df8e2c2`, then commit this container which already have `numpy` installed to a new image:

   ```
   docker commit 0a6b4df8e2c2 newpython
   ```

**Finally**, all new container need to run base on `newpython` image not `python` image, as only the `newpython` image has `numpy` installed:

```
   docker run --rm newpython python -c "import numpy; print(numpy.__version__)"
   1.20.3
```

**Additional**, for `docker run -it python a.py`, I think you misunderstand the concept. Container command like `python a.py` means the command will executed in container, so the `a.py` should be in container, not in host machine.